# Implement the law of cosine in Haskell?

Tags: list, function, haskell, list-comprehension, trigonometry

So I want to create my own cosine function using this formula: [image]

The function should return the value as long as its absolute value is greater than 0.001.

However, my code seems to have some type errors that I just don't know how to fix. I've already tried changing all types to Double, but it still doesn't work.

```
fac :: Int -> Int
fac n = if (n == 0) then 1 else n * fac (n-1)

cos :: Double -> Double
cos x = sum [cos| k <- [0..],
                  let cos = (-1) * (x^(2*k) `div` fac (2*k)) , 
                  abs (cos) > 0.001]
```

This is the error:

• Couldn't match expected type ‘Double’ with actual type ‘Int’

• In the second argument of ‘div’, namely ‘fac (2 * k)’

Comment: Well `abs cos > 0.001` is a *filter* it is *not* a stop condition, this will keep yielding values, but only remove those once `abs cos > 0.001` so you will get stuck in an infinite loop anyway?

Comment: Your current approach won't terminate; it will try values of `k` forever looking for values of `cos` that are big enough, without knowing that it will never find another one. You'll need to use `takeWhile`.

Comment: @codingbudgie: I think it might be better to use a `takeWhile`, and to use some list processing functions, not list comprehension

Comment: Hmmm... Taylor series expansion. Homework problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are basically two problems here:

- `div` is for integer division (i.e. takes integral inputs, and produces an integral output by rounding down) only. You want `(/)` for floating-point division.
- `fac` returns an `Int`, which you must explicitly convert to a floating-point number before using in division. (Many languages auto-convert from integral types to floating-point types, but Haskell does not.) You can use `fromIntegral` to convert.

Fixing these two things but nothing else, we get:

```
fac :: Int -> Int
fac n = if (n == 0) then 1 else n * fac (n-1)

cos :: Double -> Double
cos x = sum [cos| k <- [0..],
                  let cos = (-1) * (x^(2*k) / fromIntegral (fac (2*k))) , 
                  abs (cos) > 0.001]
```

This type-checks, though it has several other problems, in order from most important to least:

- You were probably hoping that Haskell would somehow magically know that once `abs cos <= 0.001` in one iteration, it will continue to be that for all future iterations, and stop iterating. But it doesn't. You said to draw `k` from `[0..]`, and so it will draw `k` from that entire list -- never finishing. You might like `takeWhile` instead.
- You've lost the exponent `k` on `-1`!
- Even setting aside whether this is the most efficient formula to start from, your implementation repeats a lot of work. Each call to `fac (2*k)` must recompute all the previous factorials it had done as intermediate results; and your `x^(2*k)` repeats some work (though to a much lesser extent).
- Reusing the name `cos` is pretty confusing. Although it doesn't technically make the program *wrong*, I'd avoid it.

I leave it to you to have fun exploring Haskell and learning how to fix these problems yourself -- I think it's well within the abilities you've shown here!

Comment: Thank you so much it works! Haha I don't know whether your last comment is a joke :D I'm so bad at haskell..but trying my best ;)

Comment: @codingbudgie It is no joke. Maybe it won't be easy -- but I do think you can do it!